# Update multiple records table from another multiple records table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't know the right title about it. 
But, Let me explain about my question.

I have 2 tables

```
PartTable
-------------------------------
ID  |  Quantity
1   |  10
2   |  10
3   |  10

TransTable
-------------------------------
TransID |ID  |  QtyIssue
1       |1   |  2
1       |2   |  2
1       |3   |  2
```

for TransTable, I'm using single query to insert.

**How to update Quantity on PartTable in single Query?**

```
Quantity = Quantity - QtyIssue
```

I'm using this update statement:

```
UPDATE PartTable SET Quantity = Quantity - (SELECT QtyIssue FROM TransTable WHERE TransID = 1)
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TransTable WHERE TransID = 1)
```

But error :

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is it possible?

Please help anyone. Thanks.

Comment: The subquery `SELECT QtyIssue FROM TransTable WHERE TransID = 1` returns three values and sql server doesn't know which one to use for the subtract operation, hence the error message.

Comment: Yes, i get it. But is it possible to update it using three values?

Comment: It is not entirely clear, at least not to me, what your desired output exactly is. Can you also post the result of the `UPDATE`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i already get the answer. yeahhh.....:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Update It by Using Derived Table

```
UPDATE  PartTable
        SET Quantity = Quantity - b.QtyIssue
FROM    PartTable a 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  SUM(QtyIssue) QtyIssue,ID
FROM    TransTable  WHERE TransID = 1
GROUP BY ID) b ON   a.ID  = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go >>

```
UPDATE parttable pt 
SET    pt.quantity = pt.quantity - (SELECT tt.qtyissue 
                                    FROM   transtable tt 
                                    WHERE  tt.transid = 1 
                                           AND tt.id = pt.id) 
WHERE  pt.id IN (SELECT tt1.id 
                 FROM   transtable tt1 
                 WHERE  tt1.transid = 1)
```